# How to parameterize git URL in shell script?

Tags: linux, git, shell

I'm writing a shell script that needs to construct a URL pointing to a file sitting in the same git repo as the script.  The script will always be run in a git repo context.  I want to parameterize as much as possible of the URL construction.

Let's say the URL is of the following form:

```
https://github.com/raw/dma/aws_config/dma-prod/cf_templates/Glue.template
```

which suggests the following generic structure:

```
<protocol>://<github_server>/raw/<repo>/<branch>/cf_templates/Glue.template
```

Getting the branch is easy:

```
   CURRENT_GIT_BRANCH = $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

I also know how to get the current project URL:

```
  CURRENT_GIT_PROJECT = $(git config --get remote.origin.url)
```

but then I'd have to do a bunch of work, stripping the `.git` extension from the project URL, and splitting out the `protocol`+`server` part from the `repo name`, so I can insert `raw` in-between them.

Is there an easier/more efficient way?

Comment: Why do you need to derive the github URL, when you already have the repository checked out locally, including all the files?

Comment: heh... good point.